# Rewrite dokuwiki internal links using regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I am currently trying to merge several wikis together but to do so, I will need to parse the links that are within the page to make them match their new location. To do so I plan to use a Perl or bash script (not very sure still though I tend to go for Perl) and to use regex to convert them so that they can match their new namespace.

Doing the conversion by itself should not be too difficult, anyway I am getting an issue since the syntax for http links and internal links is mainly the same, so I am not very sure how to deal with that, and thus I am looking for help.

As a specific example, please find the following.

One example that we must convert :

```
[[deploy_an_application|Tutorial to deploy an application]]
```

should become :

```
[[admin:deploy_an_application|Tutorial to deploy an application]]
```

which can be performed by a (using _ as a separator) :

```
s_(\[\[).*\]\]_\[\[admin\:_g
```

One example that we should NOT convert :

```
[[http://www.ibm.com|Proud home of WebSphere]]
```

To perform that I am currently foreseeing something based on :

```
s_\[\[[^http]......
```

But I am really unsure about all that, especially since I cannot really make that work...

So the question, is how can I perform this substitution on internal links without taking the http links in the process ?

Thank you very much for your help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `[[http into [^[^` or whatever string you like, 
then change `[[ into [[admin:`, 
then change back `[^[^ into [[http`